# Как сделать плавную прокрутку страницы, помогите найти ошибку

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Я питаюсь реализовать плавную прокрутку страницы, нашёл в интерненте кучу вариантов, но по какой-то непонятной причине они не работают, вот например скрипт:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.scroll-to').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Я и jqyery подключил, и попытался изменить сам скрипт, но эффекта ноль, мне бы понять по какой причине моя страница упёрлась в стену

Кстати вот вывод в консоль:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).offset() is undefined
 file:///C:/OSPanel/domains/localhost/js/script.js:138
jQuery 9
 file:///C:/OSPanel/domains/localhost/js/script.js:135
jQuery 13
script.js:138:48

Comment: В версии 3.0 jquery .bind не используется, это старый пример, вместо него используйте .on. Какое значение `$anchor.attr('href')).offset().top` вы получаете при клике (выведите в консоль) и что вы получаете при клике `$anchor.attr('href'))`  тоже выведите в консоль. Если бы в примере был html код, было бы более понятно

Comment: @Greg-- А можно ли подключить два jqery файла на одну страницу ? и 1.7 и 3.4 одновременно

Comment: отравьте результаты следующего кода
```console.log($($anchor.attr('href')))```

Comment: ReferenceError: $anchor is not defined, и что это может значит

Comment: Можно подключить и два, но зачем. пзаменить слово bind на on не так тяжело. `$anchor is not defined` это значит что без минимального примера не разобратся, а вообще что нет такой переменной (не определена).